# Printing an array with n numbers per line

Tags: c++

I was building a class with an array called myIntArray which was initialized to all 9s in the constructor. I Then built a function called printArray(int y) that prints the array with y numbers per line. The problem I have is that it prints the last 10 elements of the array as 0 when they should be all 9s. can any one tell me why??

```
class MyList
{
public:
MyList();
void printArray(int y);

private:
const static int ARRAY_SIZE{1000};
int myIntArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

};

void MyList::printArray(int y)
{
    for(int row{0}; row < ARRAY_SIZE; ++row)
        {
            for(int col{0}; col < y; ++col)
                {
                    std::cout << myIntArray[row] << " ";
                    ++row;
                }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing past the end of the array.  (I did not downvote.)

Comment: Using a debugger will make the problem here obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to access many elements past the end of an array, as someone already commented. The second loop is redundant. Consider using division remainder '%'.

```
 for(int row{0}; row < ARRAY_SIZE; ++row) {
        std::cout << myIntArray[row];
        if (!((row+1) % y) ) {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your printArray function is weird. You increment the row variable in outer loop and inner loop so you miss some of the elements because incrementing the row twice. Be aware also you can reach out of bonds depending on y’s value.